# How to realize 1 month `step` in Bokeh DateRangeSlider?

Tags: python, date, slider, bokeh

The Bokeh `DateRangeSlider` widget requires `int` values for its `step` attribute which must be the time value in milliseconds. It works well when the step is set to `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days` or `years`. However I need a **month** resolution on the slider.

When the step is set to 31 days it works well for the start date until March when instead of `1 March` I get `4 March`. Then the shift from 1th of the month in the displayed value gets bigger and bigger.

I want to be able to set and get displayed the slider range on both sides always to be the 1th day of the month e.g. `1 March`, `1 April`, `1 May`, `1 June` etc... like it is in the `DataFrame`.

Considering the following code, what would be the best way to realize it (possibly using a JS callback) ?

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import DateRangeSlider


data = {'date_start': ['201812', '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911'],  
        'date_end': [ '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911', '201912'], 
        'values' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%Y%m')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y%m')

start_date = df['Start'].min()
end_date = df['End'].max()

range_slider = DateRangeSlider(start=start_date, end=end_date, value=(start_date, end_date), step=31*24*60*60*1000, title="Date Range", callback_policy = 'mouseup', tooltips = False, width=600)

show(range_slider)import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import DateRangeSlider


data = {'date_start': ['201812', '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911'],  
        'date_end': [ '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911', '201912'], 
        'values' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%Y%m')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y%m')

start_date = df['Start'].min()
end_date = df['End'].max()

range_slider = DateRangeSlider(start=start_date, end=end_date, value=(start_date, end_date), step=31*24*60*60*1000, title="Date Range", callback_policy = 'mouseup', tooltips = False, width=600)

show(range_slider)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggling I came up with this JS callback which temporary changes the step to 1 day in order to be able to correct the date. It also changes temporary the range so that when the step is restored the slider handle remains on its position. Far from perfect but working:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, DateRangeSlider

data = {'date_start': ['201812', '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911'],  
        'date_end': [ '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907', '201908', '201909', '201910', '201911', '201912'], 
        'values' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%Y%m')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y%m')

start_date = df['Start'].min()
end_date = df['End'].max()

range_slider = DateRangeSlider(start=start_date, end=end_date, value=(start_date, end_date), step=31*24*60*60*1000, title="Date Range", callback_policy = 'mouseup', tooltips = False, width=600)

code = '''


console.log('start, end', cb_obj.start, cb_obj.end)

for (i in cb_obj.value) {
    if (getDay(cb_obj.value[i]) != 1) {
        correctDate(day, i)
    }
}

function getDay(value) {
    date = new Date(value)
    str_date = date.toString()
    day = str_date.split(' ')[2]

    return Number(day)
}

function correctDate(day, side) {
    if (day < 15) {
        console.log('day < 15')
        difference = day - 1
        difference_milliseconds = -1 * difference*24*60*60*1000
    }
    else {  
        console.log('day >= 15')
        difference = 0
        new_day = -1
        while(new_day != 1) {
            difference_milliseconds = difference*24*60*60*1000
            new_date = new Date(cb_obj.value[0] + difference_milliseconds)
            new_day = Number(new_date.getDate())

            difference += 1
        }   
    }

    cb_obj.step = 1*24*60*60*1000 // set slider step to 1 day to be able to correct

    if (side == 0) {
        cb_obj.start = cb_obj.start + difference_milliseconds
        cb_obj.value = [cb_obj.value[0] + difference_milliseconds, cb_obj.value[1]]
    }
    else if (side == 1) {
        cb_obj.end = cb_obj.end + difference_milliseconds + 4*24*60*60*1000 
        cb_obj.value = [cb_obj.value[0], cb_obj.value[1] + difference_milliseconds]    
    }

    setTimeout(resetStep, 50, cb_obj) // reset step to 31 days
}

function resetStep(cb_obj) {
    cb_obj.step = 31*24*60*60*1000
}       
'''
range_slider.js_on_change('value_throttled', CustomJS(args = {'end_date': end_date}, code=code))

show(range_slider)
```

[image]

Or maybe the best option is not to use the `DateRangeSlider` at all fo the month step. The solution below uses a `RangeSlider` in combination with a `Div` to realize the same functionality which looks much nicer:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import RangeSlider, Div, Column, CustomJS

data = {'date_start': ['2018-12', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11'],  
        'date_end': [ '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12'], 
        'values' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%Y-%m')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y-%m')

number_dates = len(list(df.date_start.unique()))

start_dates = df.date_start.to_list()
end_dates = df.date_end.to_list()

range_slider = RangeSlider(start=0, end=number_dates, value=(0, number_dates), step=1, title="", callback_policy = 'mouseup', tooltips = False, width=600, show_value = False)
div = Div(text = "Date Range: <b>" + str(start_dates[range_slider.value[0]]) + ' . . . ' + str(end_dates[range_slider.value[1]-1]) + '</b>', render_as_text = False, width = 575)

code = '''
range = Math.round(Number(cb_obj.value[1] - cb_obj.value[0]), 10)
range = range < 10 ? '0' + range : range
div.text = "Date Range: <b>" + start_dates[Math.round(cb_obj.value[0], 10)] + '&nbsp;.&nbsp;.&nbsp;.&nbsp;' + end_dates[Math.round(cb_obj.value[1], 10) + -1] + '</b>'
'''

range_slider.js_on_change('value_throttled', CustomJS(args = {'div': div, 'start_dates': start_dates, 'end_dates': end_dates}, code=code))

show(Column(div, range_slider))
```

[image]